# PHP preg_match() in mobile number

Tags: php, regex

How to make **preg_match()** in mobile number that only accepts:

"**+**" , "**63**" , "**+63**" , "**09**" at start ,

and a "**-**" than can be placed between the number?

The number should cointain only 1 "**+**" and at the beginning.

The "**-**" should be placed anywhere between the number but only once.

Limitations on 09, 63, and + 63? On 09,

Only **exact 11 digits** is possible including 09.

On 63, only **exact 12 digits** is possible including 63.

On +63, only **exact 13 digits** is possible including +63.

**Example:**

+639164455539

639164455539

09164455539

0916-4455539

Here's my code:

```
form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Input mobile number"> <br /><br /><br />
        <?php
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) {
            $submit = $_POST['submit_btn'];
            if (preg_match("/^(09|63)[\d]{9}$/m", $mobile)) {
                // valid mobile number
                echo $mobile;
            }
            else{

                echo "ERROR!";
            }
        }
    ?>
<br />
<input type="submit" id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Comment: Only if you attempted to _read_ what you posted ...

Comment: Are you saying `+09` is the valid start of a mobile number??

Comment: +09 is not a valid start of a mobile number, only +63, 63 and 09.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^(?:09|\+?63)(?:\d(?:-)?){9,10}$/m
```

It matches all examples in the updated question

See http://regex101.com/r/bS0tW2

With the added requirement of "at most one hyphen" we get

```
/^(?:09|\+?63)(?!.*-.*-)(?:\d(?:-)?){9,10}$/m
```

The negative look ahead says "from this point forward you cannot match two hyphens".

Updated demo: 
http://regex101.com/r/pZ4eJ6

Finally - your requirement about number of digits, while not exactly as you stated in your comment, can probably be met with

```
/^(?:09|\+?639)(?!.*-.*-)(?:\d(?:-)?){9}$/m
```

Which actually says:

```
(?:09|\+?639) - start with either 09 or (optional +)639
(?!.*-.*-)    - there may not be more than one hyphen in what follows
(?:\d(?:-)?){9} - there must be exactly 9 digits in what follows; don't count a (single) hyphen
```

Demo at http://regex101.com/r/zQ5lU8

If you really need exactly what you said, you need to make a bigger "or" statement. Something like this:

```
^((?:09)(?!.*-.*-)(?:\d(?:-)?){9}$|^\+?63(?!.*-.*-)(?:\d(?:-)?){10}$)
```

This basically splits the expression in two: either "one starting with the international access code", or "one that doesn't". I don't think it is better because I'm pretty sure that your "international" mobile number always starts with +639, so validating that specific sequence is better for detecting a valid mobile number. However, [I just read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_Philippines) that for the Philippines

> Mobile phone area codes are three digits long and always start with
>   the number 9, although recently new area codes have been issued with 8
>   as the starting digit, particularly for VOIP phone numbers.

You might want to consider that as you create your validation...

Comment: Hmm got error on. +63916-2481688+ it should contain only 1 **+** and **-**.

Comment: I don't understand. When I add your latest number to my demo it fails (the + at the end causes the match to fail). But why would you only allow one hyphen - and where do you allow it? Not clear from your question.

Comment: The hyphen can be placed anywhere between the number but once only.

Question is already edited, sorry for late edit.

Comment: OK I have updated my answer by adding a negative look ahead. Two hyphens now fails.

Comment: `Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\regularexpression\index.php` hmm, got an error sir.

Comment: Sorry when I copied the updated expression from the demo I didn't put the delimiters back (they are implicit on regex101.com). I have put them back.

Comment: hmm, can you add limitations on 09, 63, and + 63?
On 09, only **exact** 11 digits is possible including 09.
On 63, only **exact** 12 digits is possible including 63.
On +63, only **exact** 13 digits is possible including +63.
I'll update the question as well. This will be the last **BIG THANKS!**

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 if (preg_match("/^\+(09|63)-?[\d]{9}$/m", $mobile)) {
            // valid mobile number
            echo $mobile;
   }
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/121041)

Comment: I think you forgot **!preg_match** and I think this is the answer. **Big Thanks!**

Comment: This does not match 10 digit numbers, and it allows `+09` at the start of the number. Also it does not allow hyphens in the 9 digit string. I don't see how this is marked as "correct".

Comment: @Awlad Liton Hmm got error on. +63916-2481688+ it should contain only 1 **+** and **-**.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. I think you can make even shorter.

```
$yournumber="+639164455539";
  if (preg_match_all("/(^\+?63(?!.*-.*-)(?!.*\+.*\+)(?:\d(?:-)?){10,11}$)|(^09(?!.*-.*-)(?!.*-.*-)(?:\d(?:-)?){9}$)/",$yournumber))
{
echo "Valid";
}
else
{
  echo "Invalid number";
}
```